# Android API to change lock screen type

Tags: android, lockscreen

Is there an API to change the lockscreen type from for eg. a slide type lockscreen to a pin based lockscreen?

Comment: Seems like that would a security concern if apps could just change your lockscreen...

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible. And for good reason: Every time you switch to a secured locking mechanism (pattern, pin, etc.) Android wants you to redefine the unlock pattern (or pin, etc.)